# No visible @interface for 'forum' declares the selector 'backToLastPage'

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uiwebview

So am very new to xCode and it would help if someone could help me with this!

I'm creating an app that is very simple for the most part. I have a `UIWebView` taking me to a mobile page. This page has a **log-in** for `Facebook`. The original problem I've been having, is that since it's a mobile site I am getting a blank screen after the login is complete. I need the `UIWebView` to take me back to the original sign I clicked log-in at. I have copied some code which I think will work, but I I'm getting at error that says

> "No visible @interface for 'forum' declares the selector 'backToLastPage'"

Could someone please tell me what I need to do to fix this problem? It's probably something simple but I need some help.

```
#import "forum.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface forum ()

@end

@implementation forum



-(IBAction)switchback:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.moot.it/yopyipcommunity"];
    NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
    [myWebView loadRequest:myRequest];
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView 
        shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
        navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSString *url = [[request URL] absoluteString];

    //when user status == connected 
    //(has a access_token at facebook oauth response)
    if([url hasPrefix:@"https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth"] && 
       [url rangeOfString:@"access_token="].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        [self backToLastPage];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *url = [[webView.request URL] absoluteString];

    if([url hasPrefix:@"https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth"])
    {
        NSString *bodyHTML = 
       [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];

        //Facebook oauth response dead end: 
        //  is a blank body and a head with a script that does
        //nothing. But if you got back to your last page, 
        //  the handler of authResponseChange
        //will catch a connected status 
        //  if user did his login and auth app
        if([bodyHTML isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            [self backToLastPage];
        }
    }   
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think forum.h is separate class, backToLastPage method is declared in that class.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) forum *forum;
```

You need to create allocation for that class,

```
self.forum = [forum alloc]init];
```

and you call the method like this, `[self.forum backToLastPage];`

instead of this, `[self backToLastPage];`

Comment: Where am I suppose to post the
self.forum = [forum alloc]init]; ?

Comment: in viewDidLoad method

Comment: Do I just copy and past it or do I need anything else with it? I tried just copying and pasting it and it gave me errors.

Comment: what error? where you implemented this method backToLastPage?

Comment: I put    self.forum = [forum alloc]init];   right above    [self.forum backToLastPage];    and I'm getting the same error as before. 

I also put   @property (nonatomic, strong) forum *forum;   in my .h file.

Comment: i want to know about where is your implementation, -(void)backToLastPage{}. whether in forum class or viewcontroller class

Comment: Ok actually now it works! I added -(void)backToLastPage in my .h file. But now I'm getting a Semantic issue that says 'method definition for backToLastPage' not found